# magento1: How to get stock status instead of qty of product

Tags: magento-1.9

In this code I need to look get stock status instead of qty of a product.
What to change.

Thanks

```
<?php $qty = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); ?>
<span class="sticker-wrapper top-left"><span class="<?php if ($qty == 0) { echo  'sold-out'; } ?>">
         <?php 

                if ($qty == 0) :
                    echo $this->__('Sold');
                else :
                    echo $this->__('&nbsp;');
                endif;
        ?>
</span></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code :

```
<span class="sticker-wrapper top-left">
<span class="<?php if ($_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock() == 0) { echo 'sold-out'; } ?>"> 
  <?php 
       if ($_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()) {
         echo "&nbsp;";
        }else{ 
           echo "Sold"; 
         } 
    ?> 
 </span>
```

Comment: Is this the correct way to implement it?

    <span class="sticker-wrapper top-left"><span class="<?php if ($_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock() == 0) { echo  'sold-out'; } ?>">
         <?php 
              if ($_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()) { 
    // $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock() == 1
    echo "&nbsp;";
}else{
// $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock() == 0
echo "Sold";
}
        ?>
</span></span>

Comment: yes. I have also modified the answer.

Comment: thanks, last thing do i always need to use the else. because if i only use this it also works fine:     if ($_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock() == 0) { 
    // $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock() == 0
    echo "Sold";        Thanks.

Comment: Sometime we had to do only which works.

Answer (score 1):

Get a stock details using below lines. hope its will help you.

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
           ->loadByProduct($productId);
             print_r($stockItem);
```